# How can I get my map legend to populate with an outside dataset?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a map legend with sized circles using an outside dataset file, but the legend is not displaying the actual information needed.

It seems to work if I make an array of data within the JS code, but I need it to work with the .js file that I'm pulling from.

The JavaScript I'm utilizing is below:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
        lat: 27.964157,
        lng: -82.452606
    },
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    //    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    //     disableDefaultUI: true,
    //      gestureHandling: 'none',
    //          zoomControl: false,


});



var script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = 'https://trialscout.com/Scripts/landscapedata/tampadata_geojsonp.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
    var nctcount = feature.getProperty('count_of_nct_id');        
    return {
        icon: getCircle(nctcount)
    };
});


var icons = [];

var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
for (var key in icons) {
var type = icons[key];
var name = type.name;
var icon = type.icon;
var scale = type.scale;
var opacity = type.fillOpacity;
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\" height=\"" + 8 * scale / 8 + "\" width=\"" + 8 * scale / 8 + "\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"50\" style=\"fill: green; stroke: white; stroke-width: 1;\" opacity=\"" + opacity + "\"/></svg>'> " + name;
legend.appendChild(div);
}

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);

}


function getCircle(nctcount) {
var nctamt = nctcount;
if (nctamt <= 10) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: 'green',
        scale: 5,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        name: "<= 10"
    };
}

else if (nctamt <= 100) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: .8,
        fillColor: 'green',
        scale: 10,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        name: "<= 100"
    };
}

else if (nctamt <= 250) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: .6,
        fillColor: 'green',
        scale: 15,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        name: "<= 250"
    };
}

else if (nctamt <= 500) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: .4,
        fillColor: 'green ',
        scale: 20,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        name: "<= 500"
    };
}

else if (nctamt <= 2000) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: .2,
        fillColor: 'green',
        scale: 25,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        name: "<= 2000"
    };
}

else {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: .2,
        fillColor: 'green',
        scale: 35,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        name: "> 2000"
    };
}

}

function tslandscape_callback(response) {
map.data.addGeoJson(response);
}
```

My Fiddle for the project is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Strawmr/uoc8vwhf/7/

Comment: You did a good job breaking down and isolating your problem into "it works with X (array daya) but I need to get Y (some file??)  in format of X but I can't retrieve Y" --- however your question is a lot of extra fluff. It would take me a long time to go through your code and figure out what the format of X is, and why you cant get Y  and how your'e trying to get Y --- so try isolating the question to that.

Comment: In lieu of really knowing what's going on --- if your outside data is really a `js` file and not a JSON file you need to set up a server side request to then send the data to you, or get your server to say that outside domain is okay to pull scripts from (see CORS). But by doing so you're basically opening yourself up to security issues because you don't own that outside domain

Comment: @CodyG. I do own the outside domain. It's a geojson.js file. The link to it is in the code. The data displays on the map properly, but I can't get the circles to appear in the legend based on the scale specified in the getCircle function.

Comment: initMap is probably called before your data from your geojson.js file is loaded. Have you set up a debug log / point in order to see if the data is available when it is needed ?

Comment: The data is populating the map, so it is loading. I just need the legend to populate based on the information from the getCircle function it seems.

Comment: Can you modify your data using getCircle and then pass it to your legend function?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the code from my answer to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174137/how-to-create-sized-circles-legend-for-google-maps), and make a function that creates a fixed legend (rather than trying to generate it dynamically from your data).

```
function makeLegend(map) {
  var legendmap = {
    scale1: {population: 8},
    scale2: {population: 80},
    scale3: {population: 200},
    scale4: {population: 450},
    scale5: {population: 1900},
    scale6: {population: 5000}
  };
  var icons = [];
  // Construct the circle for each value in legendmap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var entry in legendmap) {
    // Add the circle for this entry to the map.
    var icon = getCircle(legendmap[entry].population);
    if (!icons[icon.scale])
      icons[icon.scale] = icon;
  }

  var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
  for (var key in icons) {
    var type = icons[key];
    var name = type.name;
    var icon = type.icon;
    var scale = type.scale;
    var opacity = type.fillOpacity;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\" height=\"" + 8 * scale / 8 + "\" width=\"" + 8 * scale / 8 + "\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"50\" style=\"fill: green; stroke: white; stroke-width: 1;\" opacity=\"" + opacity + "\"/></svg>'> " + name;
    legend.appendChild(div);
  }
  // add the created legend to the map
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qv7Lj0nx/5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 27.964157,
      lng: -82.452606
    },
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    styles: styles,
  });

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://trialscout.com/Scripts/landscapedata/tampadata_geojsonp.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var nctcount = feature.getProperty('count_of_nct_id');
    return {
      icon: getCircle(nctcount)
    };
  });

  makeLegend(map);
}

function getCircle(nctcount) {
  var nctamt = nctcount;
  if (nctamt <= 10) {
    return {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      fillColor: 'green',
      scale: 5,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      name: "<= 10"
    };
  } else if (nctamt <= 100) {
    return {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      fillColor: 'green',
      scale: 10,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      name: "<= 100"
    };
  } else if (nctamt <= 250) {
    return {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillOpacity: 0.6,
      fillColor: 'green',
      scale: 15,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      name: "<= 250"
    };
  } else if (nctamt <= 500) {
    return {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      fillColor: 'green ',
      scale: 20,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      name: "<= 500"
    };
  } else if (nctamt <= 2000) {
    return {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      fillColor: 'green',
      scale: 25,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      name: "<= 2000"
    };
  } else {
    return {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      fillColor: 'green',
      scale: 35,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      name: "> 2000"
    };
  }

}

function tslandscape_callback(response) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(response);
}

function makeLegend(map) {
  // entries in the legend
  var legendmap = {
    scale1: {population: 8},
    scale2: {population: 80},
    scale3: {population: 200},
    scale4: {population: 450},
    scale5: {population: 1900},
    scale6: {population: 5000}
  };
  var icons = [];
  // Construct the circle for each value in legendmap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var entry in legendmap) {
    // Add the circle for this entry to the map.
    var circle = getCircle(legendmap[entry].population);
    if (!icons[circle.scale])
      icons[circle.scale] = circle;
  }

  var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
  for (var key in icons) {
    var type = icons[key];
    var name = type.name;
    var icon = type.icon;
    var scale = type.scale;
    var opacity = type.fillOpacity;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\" height=\"" + 8 * scale / 8 + "\" width=\"" + 8 * scale / 8 + "\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"50\" style=\"fill: green; stroke: white; stroke-width: 1;\" opacity=\"" + opacity + "\"/></svg>'> " + name;
    legend.appendChild(div);
  }
  // add the created legend to the map
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}
var styles = [{
  "featureType": "all",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "administrative",
  "elementType": "geometry.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#e7e8e9"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "administrative",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#06262d"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "administrative.country",
  "elementType": "labels",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "administrative.locality",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#085c66"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#7ca7ad"
  }, {
    "visibility": "on"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#f2f2f2"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape",
  "elementType": "geometry.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#f7f8f9"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape",
  "elementType": "labels.text",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "simplified"
  }, {
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "simplified"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "poi",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "poi.park",
  "elementType": "geometry",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }, {
    "color": "#e3ece7"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "saturation": -100
  }, {
    "lightness": 45
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.highway",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "simplified"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.highway",
  "elementType": "geometry.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#e7e8e9"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.highway",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#0a5d66"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.highway",
  "elementType": "labels.icon",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }, {
    "hue": "#00e8ff"
  }, {
    "saturation": "22"
  }, {
    "gamma": "1"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.arterial",
  "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#e7e8e9"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.arterial",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#7ca7ad"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.arterial",
  "elementType": "labels.icon",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.local",
  "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#e7e8e9"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.local",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#afc6c6"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.local",
  "elementType": "labels.icon",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "simplified"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "transit",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "transit.station.airport",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "transit.station.airport",
  "elementType": "geometry.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#e7e8e9"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "transit.station.airport",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#0a5d66"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "water",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#46bcec"
  }, {
    "visibility": "on"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "water",
  "elementType": "geometry.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#afc6c6"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "water",
  "elementType": "labels.text",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#0a5d66"
  }]
}]
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#legend {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

#legend h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#legend img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```