# How do I create a legend in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, legend

I am using a very long GEOJSON file with 172 point features. I have classified them using 7 categories and trying to create a legend with the resulting data. I have gotten a few errors that I can't figure out at this point.

1. The legend formatting from the CSS is not working.
2. The circles are not working (showing as squares and not filled in with the fill colour).
   [image]

Here is the code:

```css
<style>
    #map {height: 100%; width:100%;}
    html,body { padding:0; margin:0; height:100%; }
    .gm-style .gm-style-iw {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

```js
<script>

    var map;

    function getIcons(HospStrk) {
        var HospType = ""; // marker fill colour
        var HospSize = 0; // marker size
 
        switch (true) {
            case ( HospStrk == 'Regional Stroke Centre'): HospType = '#88419D'; HospSize = 14; break;   
            case ( HospStrk == 'Designated District Stroke Centre'): HospType = '#8C96C6'; HospSize = 12; break;
            case ( HospStrk == 'TeleStroke'): HospType = '#B3CDE3'; HospSize = 10; break;
            case ( HospStrk == 'Non Designated Stroke Hospital with Stroke Services'): HospType = '#EDF8FB'; HospSize = 8; break;
            case ( HospStrk == 'Only Emergency Department Services'): HospType = '#2CA25F'; HospSize = 6; break;
            case ( HospStrk == 'Nursing Stations / Non-ED Sites'): HospType = '#99D8C9'; HospSize = 5; break;
            case ( HospStrk == 'Unknown'): HospType = '#525252'; HospSize = 4; break;
        } 
        
        return {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: HospSize,
            fillColor: HospType,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: .1,
            name: HospStrk,

        };
    };

    function makeLegend(map) {
        var legendmap = {
            cat1: {ServiceType: "Regional Stroke Centre"},
            cat2: {ServiceType: "Designated District Stroke Centre"},
            cat3: {ServiceType: "TeleStroke"},
            cat4: {ServiceType: "Non Designated Stroke Hospital with Stroke Services"},
            cat5: {ServiceType: "Only Emergency Department Services"},
            cat6: {ServiceType: "Nursing Stations / Non-ED Sites"},
            cat7: {ServiceType: "Unknown"}
        };
        var icons = [];
        var cnt=0;
        // Construct the circle for each value in legendmap.
        for (var entry in legendmap) {
            // Add the circle for this entry to the map.
            var icon = getIcons(legendmap[entry].ServiceType);
            icons[cnt] = icon;
            cnt++;
        };
            
        var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
        legend.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        legend.style.border = '3px solid #000';
        legend.style.padding = '10px';
        legend.style.margin = '10px';

        var sheet = document.createElement('style')
        sheet.innerHTML="div{font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12;}"
        legend.appendChild(sheet);
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        var tblBody =document.createElement('tbody');

        for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) { 
            var type = icons[i];
            var name = type.name;
            var icon = type.icon;
            var scale = type.scale;
            var opacity = type.fillOpacity;
            var fColor = type.fillColor;
            
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            var cell = document.createElement('td');    
            var img  = document.createElement('div');
            img.innerHTML="<svg viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\" height=\"" + scale*2 + "\" width=\"" + scale*2 + "\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"50\" style=\"fill: "+ fColor +"; stroke-width: 1;\" opacity=\"" + opacity + "\"/></svg>";
            cell.appendChild(img);
            row.appendChild(cell);
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.style.fontSize = "12px";
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
            cell.appendChild(span);
            row.appendChild(cell);

            tblBody.appendChild(row);
        };

        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        
        legend.appendChild(tbl);
        
        // add the created legend to the map
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
    };

    function initMap() {
        const mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
        const originalMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(45.870774886089386, -79.33149271169445);
        const map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            zoom: 6,
            center: originalMapCenter, 
            });
        
        var hosp = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
        hosp.loadGeoJson('./Hospitals.json');

        hosp.setStyle(function(feature) {
            var HospStrk = feature.getProperty('ServiceType'); 
            return {
                icon: getIcons(HospStrk)
            };                  
        }); 

        makeLegend(map);

    }

</script>
```

Here is a snippet of the geojson file:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "id" : 1,
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          -82.390372739999975,
          42.977287040000078
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "OBJECTID" : 1,
        "LHIN_Institution__Site_" : "Bluewater Health - Sarnia General Site",
        "Name" : "Bluewater Health - Sarnia General Site",
        "LHIN" : "Erie St. Clair LHIN",
        "Location" : "Sarnia",
        "StrokeNetwork" : "Southwestern Ontario",
        "Address" : "89 Norman St, Sarnia, Ontario N7T 6S3",
        "Email" : null,
        "Phone" : null,
        "Website" : "https://www.bluewaterhealth.ca/programs-services/cardiac-care/sarnia-lambton-district-stroke-centre-stroke-prevention-clinic",
        "StrokeServices" : "Stroke Services Available",
        "ServiceType" : "Designated District Stroke Centre",
        "TeleStroke" : "No",
        "Refer_HyperAcute" : null,
        "Refer_SecStrokePrev" : null,
        "Refer_IPAcuteStrokeCare" : null,
        "Refer_EndovascularTreatment" : "London Health Sciences Centre - University",
        "Refer_StrokeAdmission" : null,
        "Refer_TelestrokeEVT" : null,
        "NonDesignatedStrokeServices" : "No",
        "Refer_NonDesignatedEVT" : "No",
        "NonDesignatedStrokeHospital" : null,
        "EVT" : "No",
        "TeleStrokeUser" : "Yes",
        "HyperAcute" : "Yes",
        "SSPC" : "Yes",
        "AcuteStrokeIP" : "No",
        "AcuteStrokeUnit" : "Yes",
        "StrokeRehabInPatient" : "Yes",
        "Ref_IPStrReh_Name" : null,
        "OutpatientStrokeRehab" : "Yes",
        "CommunityStrokeRehab" : "No"
      }
    },
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "id" : 2,
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          -82.147076289999973,
          42.878295480000077
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "OBJECTID" : 2,
        "LHIN_Institution__Site_" : "Bluewater Health - Health-Petrolia Site",
        "Name" : "Bluewater Health - Health-Petrolia Site",
        "LHIN" : "Erie St. Clair LHIN",
        "Location" : "Petrolia",
        "StrokeNetwork" : "Southwestern Ontario",
        "Address" : "450 Blanche St, Petrolia, Ontario N0N 1R0",
        "Email" : null,
        "Phone" : null,
        "Website" : null,
        "StrokeServices" : "No Stroke Services Available",
        "ServiceType" : "Only Emergency Department Services",
        "TeleStroke" : "No",
        "Refer_HyperAcute" : "Bluewater Health - Sarnia General Site",
        "Refer_SecStrokePrev" : "Bluewater Health - Sarnia General Site",
        "Refer_IPAcuteStrokeCare" : "Bluewater Health - Sarnia General Site",
        "Refer_EndovascularTreatment" : null,
        "Refer_StrokeAdmission" : null,
        "Refer_TelestrokeEVT" : null,
        "NonDesignatedStrokeServices" : "No",
        "Refer_NonDesignatedEVT" : "No",
        "NonDesignatedStrokeHospital" : null,
        "EVT" : "No",
        "TeleStrokeUser" : "No",
        "HyperAcute" : "No",
        "SSPC" : "No",
        "AcuteStrokeIP" : "No",
        "AcuteStrokeUnit" : "No",
        "StrokeRehabInPatient" : "No",
        "Ref_IPStrReh_Name" : null,
        "OutpatientStrokeRehab" : "No",
        "CommunityStrokeRehab" : "No"
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: What default example?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself), that demonstrates your issue (where you tried to implement the legend, but it didn't work), along with some sample GeoJSON.  Related question: [How to create “sized circles” legend for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174137/how-to-create-sized-circles-legend-for-google-maps)

Comment: Sorry for my poor post @geocodezip. I have updated my script and provided you more info. I actually was able to use the post you reference to get 95% of the way there, but still a few more issues existing. I hope you can help!!

Comment: There is a syntax error in the posted CSS.  If I fix that, the posted code works for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m2qhpr08/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding the `<circle>` inside the `<svg>` in conjunction with the `<img data` attribute didn't work for me, even just trying to output simply in HTML:

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="50" width="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: #EDF8FB; stroke-width: 1;" opacity="1"/></svg>'>
```

However removing the surrounding `<img` worked, and this worked for me with your map:

```
div.innerHTML = "<svg viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\" height=\"" + scale + "\" width=\"" + scale + "\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"50\" style=\"fill: "+ fColor +"; stroke-width: 1;\" opacity=\"" + opacity + "\"/></svg> " + name;
```

It's still not picking up the styling you've defined in the `<style>` block.  The examples given at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls all define the CSS rules using JS.

Doing this then worked:

```
legend.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
legend.style.border = '3px solid #000';
legend.style.padding = '10px';
legend.style.margin = '10px';
```

Saying that, geocodezip's example at [How to create "sized circles" legend for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174137/how-to-create-sized-circles-legend-for-google-maps) didn't need to style the CSS in this way, so something else is up there.

**Update:**
To fix an issue due to multiple icons having the same scale.  You have this in the code:

```
icons[icon.scale] = icon;
```

So it's overwriting the same value in `icons` for everything with the same scale, only ending up with the last icon's value.  So you're setting `icons[6]` multiple times.

`icons` is an array, but you're treating it like a object, where you might have a unique key for each element.

Instead you just need to append into your array:

```
icons.push(icon);
```

Then the way you're looping over the array should change.  Currently it's using the `var key in icons` approach, which is for keys in an object.

Instead do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) { 
   var type = icons[i];
```

I see one issue there, it's no longer in the ascending order you'd expect. For that, a quick sort fixes it:

```
icons.sort(function(icon1, icon2) {
    return icon1.scale > icon2.scale;
});
```

Comment: In fact the problem seems specifically to be when using hexadecimal color values with the nested `<img data`> approach; a named color is fine.

Comment: Thanks so much Duncan!  It is just about there. I just noticed one other issue. It seems to be missing 2 of my legend categories. Two of the three categories with size 6 seem to be missing. When I log the legendmap object, it seems like there is some sort of index value being assigned to each object based on the size (which I am not setting anywhere). Any suggestions??? I updated the code above.